# Python Celery single base class instance for all tasks

Tags: python, celery

I have a tasks.py that contains a subclass of Task. 
According to the [docs](http://celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html) the base class is instantiated only once per tasks.

But this is only true for same tasks method. Calling a different task creates a new instance. So I can't access sessions via `get_sessions` created with `create_session`. How may I have only a single instance that is shared between different tasks?

```
class AuthentificationTask(Task):
    connections = {}

    def login(self, user, password, server):

    if not user in self.connections:
        self.connections = {user: ServerConnection(verbose=True)}
    # from celery.contrib import rdb
    # rdb.set_trace()

    self.connections[user].login(user=user, password=password, server=server)


@task(bind=True, max_retries=1, queue='test', base=AuthentificationTask)
def create_session(self, user, password, server):
    self.login(user, password, server)


@task(bind=True, max_retries=1, queue='test', base=AuthentificationTask)
def get_sessions(self, user, password, server):
    return self.connections[user].sessions
```

Comment: Why did someone downvote this question? Seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `task_cls` arg for your Celery application like this:

```
class AuthentificationTask(Task):

    def example(self):
        logger.info('AuthentificationTask.example() method was called')


@celery.task(bind=True)
def test_my_task(self):
    # call AuthentificationTask.example
    self.example()

app = celery.Celery(
   __name__,
   broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
   task_cls=AuthentificationTask,
   # other args
)
```

In this case will be use your custom class for all tasks as default.

Comment: Thanks @Danila Ganchar. I tried your solution.

Added: 

<!-- language: python -->

        (Pdb) self.app.task_cls
 u'provisioning.tasks:AuthentificationTask  


But I can't find my login method, neither `self.login` nor `self.app.login`.  

<!-- language: python -->

   File "/home/gt0015/Development/Python/acdc/webdisplay/provisioning/tasks.py", line 24, in test_connection
     self.app.login(user, password, server)
 AttributeError: 'Celery' object has no attribute 'login'

Comment: @GunnarThielebein answer was updated. you can check it

Comment: I had the same problem. I found that using this suggestion (provide `task_cls` arg to Celery constructor) did not resolve it.

Comment: @DavidSchneider this is strange. which version of `celery`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this was an issue on my site caused by reinitialising `self.connections` each time.

```
self.connections = {user: ServerConnection(verbose=True)}
```

In further tests `base` was instantiated only once for all (different) tasks. Thanks @Danila Ganchar for suggesting an alternative approach. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track by making `connections` a class variable on `AuthentificationTask`. That makes it available as a property on *the class itself* (i.e. as `AuthentificationTask.connections`). When you reference `self.connections` in the login method, I believe Python is looking for an *instance* variable `connections`, not the class variable of the same name. For the desired behavior, replace `self.connections` (in both `login` and `get_sessions`) with `AuthentificationTask.connections`.